# Why all the Dlls are not loaded in drop down

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function like this

```
 public void SetOperationDropDown()
        {
            cmbOperations.DataSource = PluginManager.GetAllPlugins();

            if(cmbOperations.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cmbOperations.SelectedItem = cmbOperations.Items[0];
            }
        }
```

This function should get the name of all dlls

```
public class PluginManager
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This function gets the name of the plugins and return that in a List<string>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> GetAllPlugins()
{

    DirectoryInfo objDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("Plugins");
    FileInfo[] args = objDirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.dll");

    List<string> assemblyNames = new List<string>();
    Assembly[] oAssemblies = new Assembly[args.Length];

    for(int assemblyCount = 0;assemblyCount < args.Length;assemblyCount++)
    {
        string executablePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

        oAssemblies[assemblyCount] = Assembly.LoadFile(executablePath.Remove(0,6) + "\\Plugins\\" + args[assemblyCount].Name);

        try
        {
            foreach(Type oType in oAssemblies[assemblyCount].GetTypes())
            {
                // Check whether class is inheriting from IMFDBAnalyserPlugin.
                if(oType.GetInterface("IMFDBAnalyserPlugin") == typeof(IMFDBAnalyserPlugin))
                {
                    assemblyNames.Add(args[assemblyCount].Name.Substring(args[assemblyCount].Name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Passing data one application domain to another.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("AssemblyNames", assemblyNames.ToArray());
    return assemblyNames;
}
```

and should be populated in the drop down when returned here

```
        //Checks for the selectedItem in the cmbOpearions dropdown and make call to appropriate functions.


  string assemblyName = Convert.ToString(cmbOperations.SelectedValue);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);

    int fileExtensionPos = assemblyName.LastIndexOf(".");
    string fileName = assemblyName.Substring(0, fileExtensionPos);

    Type localType = assembly.GetType(fileName + "." + fileName);
```

But it is not getting every dlls created from this way

```
 Type localType = assembly.GetType(fileName + "." + fileName);
```

I need to load the complete list of dlls in the drop down.

Where I am going wrong???

Comment: What events are being logged through your exception handler?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know where it doesn't work? Does the "args" variable contain anything? I suspect your problem is the way you build paths. You should be using the Path class, not string operations.

To get the current executable directory:

```
string executablePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

You should use that to build your DirectoryInfo at the beginning of the GetAllPlugins() method too.
To build a path with a subfolder:

```
string pluginPath = Path.Combine(executablePath, "Plugin");
```

To get all files in the plugin subdirectory that have the dll extension:

```
string[] pluginFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pluginPath, "*.dll");
```

Note that the filenames returned contain the whole path. You don't need to append anything:

```
foreach (string fileName in pluginFiles)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
    List<Type> types = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();
    foreach (Type type in types.FindAll(t => t.GetInterface("IMFDBAnalyserPlugin") != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

should work.

Also, don't use substring, if you want the file names, with or without extension, you should use Path.GetFileName or Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension.

And use this method to instantiate your plugin:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx